# What does "Worldwide applications US" means in Google Patents?

Tags: google-patents, worldwide

What does "Worldwide applications US" means in Google Patents? [This is the pattent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20190385238A1)

[image: eWorldwide applications US]

Will this patent infringe if used in Europe and elsewhere outside the US?

Comment: Please add a link to the webpage so we can answer.

Comment: It seems you edited the link to a different document which makes some of my answer no longer relevant. I've edited the answer to be consistent with the changes in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section in a Google Patents page titled "Worldwide applications" is a list of applications filed associated with this patent or application. Patent applications are sometimes filed in different countries for the same invention. There were no other patents or applications listed in other countries I could find.

Patents are territorial and a US patent only provides protection in the US. If you are doing business in another country the issued patent shouldn't stop you. However, I always recommend consulting with an actual patent attorney in such matters. **While your linked patent isn't a problem, there is no guarantee there aren't other relevant patents that exist and are still active.**

I am not a patent attorney myself so this isn't legal advice.